# Magento1.9 - How to include customer id in export customer csv

Tags: magento-1.9, export, customer-attribute, customer-csv

I'm using Magento1.9.3.8 and I want to include customer `id/entity_id` of a customer in CSV from exporting customer data (`System > Import/Export > Export > Customers`). right now I'm only getting this:

Attached the screen shot :

[image]

Comment: Hello @Jojo, Did you checked my answer? Is it helpful for you or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add customer_id(entity_id) in export CSV using following way :

You just simply add entity_id field in `$validAttrCodes` array in following file:

> /app/code/core/Mage/ImportExport/Model/Export/Entity/Customer.php

You can change in `public function export()` function.

```
 public function export()
 {
     $collection = $this->_prepareEntityCollection(Mage::getResourceModel('customer/customer_collection'));
     $validAttrCodes = $this->_getExportAttrCodes();
     array_unshift($validAttrCodes, "entity_id"); //Add Customer Id(entity_id) field.
     $writer = $this->getWriter();
     ---------------------------------
     ---------------------------------
 }
```

You can override `/app/code/core/Mage/ImportExport/Model/Export/Entity/Customer.php` file in your custom module.

[image]

I hope it will helpful for you.